# BeanUtils setProperty throws an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

**Environment details**

I have three projects:

- *Project A*: a Java REST service application
- *Project B*: a Java client app
- *Project C*: a simple list of POJOs

The first two projects have the third as dependency.

**Data flow**

*Project B* makes an *HTTP* request to *Project A* which replies using a model object of *Project C* converting it to *JSON*.

*Project B* decodes the *JSON* response using [**JSONObject**](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) and tries to obtain the original POJO object using [**BeanUtils**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/).

**Code example**

ExamplePOJO class (part of *Project C*):

```
public class ExamplePOJO {

    private String id;

    private AnotherPOJO anotherPOJO;

    public void setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public void setAnotherPOJO(AnotherPOJO anotherPOJO ) {
         this.anotherPOJO = anotherPOJO ;
    }

    public AnotherPOJO getAnotherPOJO() {
         return anotherPOJO ;
    }

}
```

*Project A* example endpoint:

```
@Path("/sample")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getExampleResponse() {

    try {

        ServiceResponse<ExamplePOJO> response = new ServiceResponse<ExamplePOJO>();

        ExamplePOJO eo = new ExamplePOJO();
        eo.setId("1");

        AnotherPOJO ap = new AnotherPOJO();
        eo.setAnotherPojo(ap);

        response.setResponse(eo);

        return ((ResponseBuilder) Response.ok().entity(response)).type("application/json").build();

    } catch(Exception E) {
        //error
    }
}
```

*Project A* response object container:

```
public class ServiceResponse<T> {

    private T response;

    public T getResponse() {
        return this.response;
    }

    public void setResponse(T response) {
         this.response = response;
    }

}
```

The interesting part, *Project B*:

```
public void callService() {

    //....HTTP request...

    //json object
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

    //ServiceResponseEquivalent is the same as the ServiceResponse object of *Project A*
    decodeResponse(json, ServiceResponseEquivalent.class, ExamplePOJO.class);

}


//this is a recursive function
public <T, V> T void decodeResponse(JSONObject json, Class<?> responseModel, Class<V> responseObjectModel) {

    //this is the same as the ServiceResponse object of *Project A*
    Object reflectedInstance = responseModel.newInstance();

    //here I got the field "response" of ServiceResponse
    Field[] fields = reflectedInstance.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field field: fields) {

         //I got the json object based on the field name
         Object objectFromResponse = json.get(field.getName());

         if(objectFromResponse instanceof JSONObject) {

             //this is the "response" property of *ServiceResponse* which I know is an instance of *ExamplePOJO* class (because who calls this function pass *Class<V> responseObjectModel*
             if(if(field.getName().equals("response")) {

                  //recursive call
                  objectFromResponse = decodeResponse(json.getJSONObject(field.getName()), responseObjectModel, responseObjectModel);
             } 
             //here I found another object inside the "response" object but I don't know which class is it. In this case it's an instance of *AnotherPOJO*
             else {

                 //I try to get the class from the name of the property: in order to work, the property must be named as its class
                 String className = "com.example.packace." + field.getName().toUpperCase().charAt(0) + field.getName().substring(1, field.getName().length());

                //className = com.example.package.AnotherPOJO                       
                //recursive call
                objectFromResponse = decodeResponse(json.getJSONObject(field.getName()), Class.forName(className), responseObjectModel);

                //I try to set the object inside the response one
                //HERE IT FAILS
                BeanUtils.setProperty(reflectedInstance, field.getName(), objectFromResponse);

             }
             //here we found another Object but we don't know 
         } else {

             //I add the element
             BeanUtils.setProperty(reflectedInstance, field.getName(), objectFromResponse);
         }
    }

}
```

**JSON example**

The client receive this *JSON*:

```
{
    "response": { //response is an instance of ExamplePOJO
        "id":"1",
        "anotherPOJO":{
             [...]
        }
    },
    [ ...other fields...]
 }
```

**The problem**

When the *decodeResponse* tries to decode the *AnotherPOJO* object inside the recursive call throws this exeption:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke com.example.package.ExamplePOJO.setAnotherPOJO on bean class 'class com.example.package.ExamplePOJO' - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "com.example.package.AnotherPOJO" but expected signature "com.example.package.AnotherPOJO"

As it's obvious from the exception, the objects are an instance of the same class.

Any ideas?

---

Which could be a better approach to decode objects of unknown class? This:

```
String className = "com.example.packace." + field.getName().toUpperCase().charAt(0) + field.getName().substring(1, field.getName().length());

 //className = com.example.package.AnotherPOJO                      
 //recursive call
 objectFromResponse = decodeResponse(json.getJSONObject(field.getName()), Class.forName(className), responseObjectModel);
```

has the obvious problem that the field must be named as its class.

Comment: Have you checked for possible duplicate classes in the classpath?

Comment: Yes of course, I use gradle to manage dependencies

Comment: Another idea that comes to mind derives from the fact that you're using generics and mixing them with reflection access which during in runtime evaluation might pose some issues.

Comment: Yes but I think it should work.. the error itself it's strange, it says  "had objects of type "com.example.package.AnotherPOJO" but expected signature "com.example.package.AnotherPOJO": this has no sense

Comment: The is a difference in classes. Please check out the mistype in the bolded words. _com.example. **package** .ExamplePOJO.setAnotherPOJO on bean class 'class com.example. **pacjage** .ExamplePOJO'_
_String className = "com.example . **packace** ."_

Comment: Well I wrote the error just for SO question, so that was a typo error. The original exception reports exactly the same packages and classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be class loading issue.
Look at source of `Class.forName(String)` , it uses class loader from caller. This could be not same as the class loader that loaded your target `responseModel`, thus, instead of it try following:

```
//recursive call
objectFromResponse = decodeResponse(
    json.getJSONObject(field.getName()),
    Class.forName(className, true, responseModel.getClassLoader()),
    responseObjectModel);
```

this should ensure that the model subhierarchy classes are loaded by same class loader.

Answer (score 0):

You have the information about the class in the `field` variable.  Call `field.getType()` to get the class of the current field/property ...

```
         //here I found another object inside the "response" object.  Use information from field to get class.
         else {

             objectFromResponse = decodeResponse(json.getJSONObject(field.getName()), field.getType(), responseObjectModel);
```

**Note:** I'd recommend Jackson to convert JSON to java objects.